# How to use a JS library which is already provided by an html designer in React component, the js library is nice-select.sj?

Tags: reactjs, import-libraries

I have a html designed by a HTML Designer. He has used *nice-select.js* for a dropdown menu. I imported it into my *index.html* and executed this :

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(".drop").niceSelect();
}
```

And it works fine when it is loaded in the first page. But on clicking a menu item which points to a different component, the js does  not initiated here and the design does not go for that component.

Now how to use this `$` function in `ComponentdidMountMethod()`?

I have install the jquery using npm install jquery --save and tried to use it but got an error `niceSelect is not a function`.

Can anyone help in this regards.

Thanks in advance.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import{Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';

$(".drop").niceSelect();
```

This gives an error nice select is not a function.

Comment: You preferably shouldn't. Using jQuery plugins that weren't written to be used in SPA is a good way to have memory leaks.

Comment: But I need it to work,  I know it should work as it will not act as an SPA as I have SSR implemented to,  on referesing the page it works but internally through onclick it need to call the nice-select method

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the problem but it's very likely that `$` that is used outside React app is global, so you don't need to import it and use window.$ instead. Let me know if this works.

Comment: No it does not works

Comment: Consider providing https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. It's impossible to help you without knowing what's going on on your side.

Comment: Thank you very much  estus , your  one just worked

Comment: componentDidMount()
 {
  window.$(".drop").niceSelect();
        }

Comment: @estus, can you please tell why I am getting an error , when refreshing the page

`code` Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): window.$ is not a function

Comment: This likely means that jQuery wasn't loaded at this point or was loaded in a way that doesn't provide $ variable. As I said, the question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's impossible to get help on SO in another way because other users don't have any idea what's going on on your side. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved this problem in this way.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import $ from 'jquery';
import '../../css/nice-select.css';
import '../../js/nice';

class Name extends React.Component{
render(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.drop').niceSelect();
      });
    return (
        <select class="drop">...</select>
    );
 }
}

export default Name;
```